# Pycharm is highlighting syntax for python2, but I am using python3

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm community edition 2017.1.5 and I have some problem....

I am working in Python 3.6.1 but PyCharm is highlighting for python2.

For example he is not allowing me to use print() function, because he is detecting print statement there. (That mean that it is only about syntax, because he know print() function but when I use it he says that it is print statement)

EDIT:

Its not finding print statement from python2 it says: `Statement expected, found Py:PRINT_KEYWORD` and it doesn't work like python2 print

EDIT 2:

I don't know why but when I disable Pyxl plugin it is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can configure python interpreter for PyCharm in Settings > Project Interpreter. Or to reconfigure default interpreter Settings > Default Project > Project Interpreter.

Comment: Have you more than one version of python installed? The configuration is applied to the project you using in tests? I use the both versions and this ever works, just try restart pycharm after setting up. On this page have a more detailed information https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I fixed it! I don't know why but when I disable Pyxl plugin it is working correcly

Comment: What do you use Pyxl for ?

Comment: I dont even know what is that.